# How do I run a single line or part of code in Colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory, execute

How do I run just part of code in Colab notebook?

For example

```
degrees = np.arange(0.0, 361, 1)
print(degrees)
```

might be part of a complete notebook to plot a sin function.
How do I run just this part of the code for debugging?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Make a selection of the line you want to run and then press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER (or click on Runtime->Run selection).